# Dynamic switching with a predicate

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

Suppose I have a monad `M`, a function*

```
foo :: forall t. Frameworks t => Int -> M (Behavior t State)
```

and a predicate

```
pred :: State -> Bool
```

I'd like to get a value* (in whatever monad necessary)

```
bar :: forall t. Frameworks t => Behavior t State
```

such that `bar` is exactly `foo n`, until the point that the state conveyed by the signal satisfies `pred`, at which point `bar` switches to `foo (n+1)`, and this repeats. `n` starts at any arbitrary `Int`, say 1.

I'm having a lot of fun learning FRP, but this particular problem is giving me trouble.

---

* <sup>Also considering the case substituting `Behavior t` for `Event t`</sup>

Comment: What monad is `M`, it might matter? Also, you say "`n` starts at some int", but where do you get `n` from?

Comment: In my particular case ``M`` is ``Rand`` from ``RandomMonad``. The ``Behavior t State``s are a series of randomly generated environments, and ``n`` starts at 1, to signify starting with the first environment.

Comment: Ah, so `n` is a fixed argument of the function, not a changing `Behaviour` or so.

Comment: Are you sure about `bar`'s type? Shouldn't that be `bar :: forall t. Frameworks t => M (Behavior t State)`?

Comment: ``M (Behavior t State)``, or ``Moment t (M (Behavior t State))`` or something else yes, I intended ``bar`` to be what some monadic value is bound to.

Comment: Independently of the monad issue: It is not possible to turn a Behavior back into an Event as the former represent continuously varying values. Things like flank detection are not available in reactive-banana. I recommend to use an Event for the State.